# Why can't Drupal write to the database after migrate/restore?

Tags: 7, database, backups

When I want to do more development on a live site, I usually make a copy of the files and database on my local LAMP install and play with it there.

Now I'm finding that if I copy the database to local using [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) or importing/exporting with phpMyAdmin, the local Drupal can only read from the database. It displays pages, but any edits or admin changes don't get saved. No errors, just nothing changes.

I've tried clearing all caches and running update.php. I'm running the same Drupal version live and locally. If I install Drupal locally from scratch, no problems at all.

What am I missing here... or is there a better way to achieve production/live cloning?

Comment: Your cloning method is fine... more experimentation is needed to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a schoolboy error on my part. I didn't have [mod_rewrite enabled](http://www.open-craft.com/blog/enabling-clean-urls-drupal-clean-ubuntu) on my local environment, so clean URLs weren't working.

Comment: I just got caught out with this too. Thanks for posting the answer to your own question. Much appreciated. Now... to add this to the provisioning script for new VMs.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a Drupal issue. It's more fitted for [webmasters.stackexchange.com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com.).

Make sure your user is granted all privileges.
See [lamphowto](http://lamphowto.com) and [ApacheMySQLPHP](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP)